# Aggregating data from lists inside lists

Tags: r

Below I will put my reproduceable example. Right now when I am doing a bunch of regression type work across many different sources (say 50 things) I aggregate each one in a list and then combine those lists together for easy storage. The structure is the same for each list, it just holds different data. What is the best way I can go about aggregating specific parts? In this example, whats the fastest way to combine ds1,ds2,ds3 & ds4, which are embedded into different lists?

```
set.seed(50)
df1 <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10))
set.seed(50)
df2 <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10))
set.seed(50)
df3 <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10))
set.seed(50)
df4 <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10))


rs1 <- rep(0.05,5)
rs2 <- rep(0.03,5)
rs3 <- rep(0.06,5)
rs4 <- rep(0.09,5)

ds1 <- rep(0.04,5)
ds2 <- rep(0.04,5)
ds3 <- rep(0.04,5)
ds4 <- rep(0.04,5)

rsdsList1 <- list(rs1,ds1)
rsdsList2 <- list(rs2,ds2)
rsdsList3 <- list(rs3,ds3)
rsdsList4 <- list(rs4,ds4)


mg1 <- list(df1,rsdsList1)
mg2 <- list(df2,rsdsList2)
mg3 <- list(df3,rsdsList3)
mg4 <- list(df4,rsdsList4)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? `lapply(list(mg1, mg2, mg3, mg4), '[[', 1)` will create a list with just those elements, and `do.call(rbind, lapply(list(mg1, mg2, mg3, mg4), '[[', 1))` will `rbind` them.

Comment: I think I was over complicating it. Using lapply in that fashion is what I was after, from there I can use all sorts of things to summarize the data.

Comment: Happy to mark your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect, into a single list, the nth elements of multiple lists with:

```
lapply(list(mg1, mg2, mg3, mg4), '[[', n)
```

So in your case, `lapply(list(mg1, mg2, mg3, mg4), '[[', 1)` will create the list that you're after.

You can name the list elements that you iterate over with `lapply` to have those names transferred to elements of the output list, e.g.

```
lapply(list(mg1=mg1, mg2=mg2, mg3=mg3, mg4=mg4), '[[', 1)
```

or wrap the `lapply` in `setNames`:

```
setNames(lapply(list(mg1, mg2, mg3, mg4), '[[', 1), paste0('mg', 1:4))
```